# Can I dynamically select GET or POST type in an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

Consider code below that intercepts form submit event, in this case from two different forms.

```
$("#aaa, #bbb").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#ccc").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Question - if `#aaa` requires `GET`, but `#bbb` requires `POST`, can I detect and alter the `type` parameter in the above code?  How?

My naive solution would be to duplicate the above code twice, one for `#aaa` only and one for `#bbb` and have GET in one block and POST in the other ..

Comment: `e.target.id` would be `aaa` or `bbb`

Comment: So read the method that you set on the form.

Comment: Though, if you put GET on the aaa form and POST on the bbb form, then it could be as simple as grabbing the form method

Comment: I think `e.target.method` is what I am looking for

Comment: `form.attr("method")` will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use the event and read the method you set on the form.

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log(evt.target.method);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <button>Get</button>
</form>
<form method="post">
  <button>Post</button>
</form>
```